# Print recursively all directories and subdirectories

Tags: shell-script, directory, recursive

I am trying to print all directories and sub directories with a recursive function but I get only the first directory. Any help?

```
counter(){
    list=`ls $1`
    if [ -z "$(ls $1)" ]
    then 
        exit 0
    fi
    echo $list
    for file in $list
    do 
      if [ -d $file ]
      then 
            echo $file
            counter ./$file
      fi
    done
}

counter $1
```

Comment: `tree -d path/to/location` or `find /path/to/location -type d`.  Also, please don't post screenshots of text; just put the code into your question.  Also also, don't parse `ls`.  Just use `for file in /path/to/location/*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter(){
    for file in "$1"/* 
    do 
    if [ -d "$file" ]
    then 
            echo "$file"
            counter "$file"
    fi
    done
}

counter "$1"
```

Run it as `./script.sh .` to recursively print directories in under the current directory or give the path to some other directory to traverse.

Comment: any explanation why the original coded  did not work.

Comment: @Jasen that solution doesn't follow the sub-directories properly. `-d` check fails because current working directory is not set properly. So in the recursive calls a directory change is needed.